# intellij sql bug with timezones

Tags: sql, intellij-idea

```
select now()
union all
select now() where now()::time at time zone 'Asia/Hong_Kong' > '12:00'::time
```

shows different behaviour in postgres client. Timezone seems to be ignored by intellij.

[image]

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson is this a bug, why is this happening, whats the best way to make both clients behave the same

Answer (score 0):

IDE always uses UTC timezone on the client's side. You can set the Time zone in "Data Source and Drivers settings dialog -> Options" tab

Comment: this is a bug then, sql isn't a client side language, it should be getting timezone from the server, where the code is executed. I connect to multi servers in different timezones.

Comment: Feel free to add comments to the related issue on YouTrack: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/DBE-8756

Comment: that issue was closed immediately when I initially reported it. Glad to see it is reopened.